# In the diagram, is the voltage of Rc (1 kΩ) 10 V or 5 V?

Tags: transistors

[image]

Q1) At first it looks like all 5 V of the top terminal is used by the 1kΩ resistor and so Ic = 5 mA, however, if I replace the terminals with a 10 V Vcc source and look at the right loop, it looks to me as 10 V is used by the 1 kΩ resistor leaving V0 = 0, and Ic = 0.1 mA. I think it's the former option but I feel like I am misunderstanding something from the terminal voltages in the diagram.

Q2) The question says to assume the 100 Ω resistor has no loading effect on the bias network. Does this mean to ignore it when doing calculations for Vin on the left loop? Do I assume the voltage of Re = 0 and do I do a Thévenin equivalent of the left side and find R1 like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add +5V to all the voltages to make the -5V node ground, then the output voltage will be +5V. In any case there is 5V across a 1kΩ resistor so the collector current must be 5mA.

If you assume the 100Ω resistor has no loading effect on the bias network, that means that you can assume the base current is zero, so the bias network is a simple unloaded voltage divider.

Don't take the exact 'answer' too seriously, they've rounded the current to two significant digits then provided the answer to more than three.

Comment: thanks for that, for the second part I understand why we assume the base current is 0, but does this mean I also assume that the voltage drop across the 100Ω resistor is 0. I kind of interpreted the statement 'assume the 100Ω resistor has no loading effect on the bias network' as it has no voltage drop across it so I can replace it with just a piece of wire. Would this be incorrect? Is the statement meant to be interpreted as ONLY Ib = 0 and nothing else?

Comment: If there is no base current, what will the emitter current be? The statement is meant to imply that the current gain of the transistor is very high so the base current is insignificant.

Comment: Ib will = Ic, I guess I misinterpreted the statement as I assumed the 100Ω resistor was null which is why I got the wrong answer. I will redo it but account for the voltage drop across it now. Thanks for answering

Comment: It is sort of a tricky way to put it-  assumes  you know intuitively that base current is a fraction of emitter current.